# ¿Como obtener las propiedades de el contenedor padre?

Tags: java, java-swing

Buenas, quisiera saber como obtener las propiedades de contenedor padre, por ejemplo: Si yo agrege un panel a un JFrame quisiera que el panel obtenga el tamaño del componente que lo esta manteniendo o consiga su layout.

¿Algun metodo(s) para optener las propiedades del contenedor padre?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la clase de utilidad SwingUtilities, ofrece métodos muy practicos, usa [getAncestorOfClass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getAncestorOfClass%28java.lang.Class,%20java.awt.Component%29) y tendrás el primer componente del tipo que indiques.